# XML Files which are serialized using XmlTextWriter and then read using XmlTextReader are sometimes corrupted

Tags: c#, xml

We have a product which uses 'XmlTextWriter' in C# - .NET 2.0 to create a large number of small XML Files.  These files are then repeatedly read using 'XmlTextReader'.

We have found that in very rare cases on a few customer machines the contents of the XML File is replaced by a large number of white spaces.  Once this happens the 'XmlTextReader' will obviously fail to read the XML File with the error "Root Element is missing".

Here are the logic details:

1. When writing a new Xml File - the file is first written to a temporary folder using :

   ```
   XmlTextWriter xDoc = new XmlTextWriter(Path, Encoding.UTF8);
   ```
2. Once the file is written to the temporary folder - 'XmlTextReader' is used to verify the file.
3. If and only if the file is verified then it is copied to the final location.
4. Over a few days the file is read multiple times using:

   ```
   XmlTextReader xDoc = new XmlTextReader(Path);
   ```
5. In some rare cases the reader fails with the error 'Root Element is Missing' and we see that the XML File now contains a number of whitespaces and no XML data.

Here are some code extracts:

This code is used for the serialization.
(Keep in mind that the serialization is done to a temporary folder and only copied to the final location once the temporary XmlFile is verified.)

```
            public void SerializeWithXmlTextWriter(XMLMetaData instance, string Path)
    {
        instance.CommitLists();

        #region XmlTextWriter

        XmlTextWriter xDoc = null;

        try
        {
            xDoc = new XmlTextWriter(Path, Encoding.UTF8);
            xDoc.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

            xDoc.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"");
            xDoc.WriteStartElement("MD");
            xDoc.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            xDoc.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsd", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");


// A number of other elements are written here

            xDoc.WriteEndElement();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (xDoc != null)
            {
                xDoc.Close();
                xDoc = null;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

This code is used for the deserialization.
(it is also used to verify the file after serialization.)

```
            public XMLMetaData DeserializeWithXmlTextReader(string Path)
    {
        XMLMetaData instance = new XMLMetaData();

        #region XmlTextReader

        XmlTextReader xDoc = null;

        try
        {
            xDoc = new XmlTextReader(Path);



            while (xDoc.Read())
            {
                switch (xDoc.Name)
                {
                    //Each element is processed using a case statement
                    //Omitted from this code sample
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (xDoc != null)
            {
                xDoc.Close();
                xDoc = null;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        return instance;
    }
```

We've been trying to solve this issue for a number of months and cannot get anywhere since it only happens on a few client machines out of thousands.  We have never been able to replicate it on our development and test machines.

We have had reports of the issue vanishing when backup applications are stopped.  We also have a customer who only seems to have issues when running Visual Studio.

Also for customers with this problem - it only seems to happen every few weeks!

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Simon

Comment: As you may notice I am not calling Flush() before I Close() the XmlTextWriter.

If you look at samples on MSDN - it seems that there is no need for Flush() to be called.

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx)

Comment: don't assume that MSDN code samples show best practices, or even work. I've spent time debugging code which was copy-pasted from MSDN before.

Comment: @Peter - Yes I agree with you completely.  If you look at this link [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.flush.aspx) it seems that Flush() is only needed if you do not call Close().  I will try some tests using Flush().  

The thing is that the contents of the file are correct before the file copy takes place.  It is later that the contents of the file are corrupted!  Also the current code only fails for a handful of our 5000+ users.

Comment: You should never use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. These have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` and `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: @John...wished the class would indicate its deprecated without me hunting for it when using VS.  Would have saved me a lot of wasted time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state that the file is verified, then copied, and that the verified file later breaks. I can see at least four possibilities:

1. Race condition. The problem occurs because you're reading the file at the same time as copying a new version to replace it.
2. The copying process is what goes wrong.
3. The file is successfully copied and later blanked by some other process.
4. The file is successfully copied and later blanked by a bug in XmlTextReader while you're reading the config.

The solution to 1 is to use cross-process synchronisation - e.g. semaphores.

To investigate 2, you can check the file after copying.

To be paranoid about 3 and 4 you can ensure that the copy is created read-only, and for 4 you can pass XmlTextReader a FileStream opened read-only rather than a path.

If none of these help, at least you'll have ruled out a few possibilities.

Comment: 1 and 2 are not possible.  I will implement code to protect against 3 and 4.  My suspicion is that point 4 is the cause. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We have encountered the same problem at least since we switched to .Net 2.0 .

We write to a temp-file using 'XmlTextWriter' and ISO-8859-1 encoding,  and then copy it afterwards.
We get an empty file, size 0.

We use Flush before close but that doesn't work either.

This happens very rarely, we have approx 4000 users and it occurs approximately once a month. Out hypothesis is that there is an internal error that does not give an exception.

We use the file for settings so our current workaround is to generate default values if this problem is encountered when reading.

We are also using Formatting.Indented, maybe this is the culprit.

Our code:

```
    Public Sub Save(ByVal st As Stream, Optional ByVal AttachComment As Boolean = True)

    Dim xtw As New XmlTextWriter(st, Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"))

    xtw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented

    xtw.WriteStartDocument()

    'Header.
    If AttachComment Then
        xtw.WriteComment(GenerateCreationComment())
    End If

    xtw.WriteStartElement("SektionsdataFile")

    xtw.WriteStartElement("Header")
    WriteStringElement(xtw, "FileType", "Settings")
    WriteStringElement(xtw, "FormatVersion", CurrentFormatVersion)
    xtw.WriteEndElement()

    'Settings.
    xtw.WriteStartElement("Settings")

    SaveSettingsCategory(xtw, Application)
    SaveSettingsCategory(xtw, Behaviour)
    SaveSettingsCategory(xtw, Calculation)
    SaveSettingsCategory(xtw, Forms)
    SaveSettingsCategory(xtw, Hardware)
    SaveSettingsCategory(xtw, Layout)
    SaveSettingsCategory(xtw, License)
    SaveSettingsCategory(xtw, Paths)
    SaveSettingsCategory(xtw, Printing)

    xtw.WriteEndElement()

    xtw.WriteEndElement()

    xtw.WriteEndDocument()

    xtw.Flush()

    xtw.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: @AmnisJonas - thank you for confirming that this issue is also happening to other developers.  

I also think that there is some sort of bug in .NET 2.0 where the user.config settings file is corrupted in a similar manner.  I thought this issue was limited to the XmlSerializer class but it seems that it isn't.

We have had many cases in multiple products where the user.config settings file is corrupted and its contents simply contains a number of whitespaces.

Comment: A year has past since I posted this issue - and we are still having some issues with XML serialization and corruption.  Have you had any luck from your end?  It would be great if you could help us out if you have.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use

```
using(XmlWriter xmlw = XmlWriter.Create(String, XmlWriterSettings))
{
  // your code here
}
```

as a boilerplate for creating xml docs. Try it, then come back if it fails too (I'd be surprised). Also use `using` construct for reading XMLs.

Usage of `XmlTextReader` is [not recommended by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1af7xa52.aspx) (see notes).

Comment: thank you for the pointer.  I will modify the code as you suggested.  It will be a while until we can verify that the issue has been solved since it is rarely replicated.

Comment: This did not work for me either.  Seems there is a bug in the compact framework in writing XML using XMLTextWriter.  I had to go back to the old way of writing files... using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream(ConfigFile,FileMode.Truncate)) {XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); String text = doc.InnerXml;   filestream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text),0, text.Length); filestream.Dispose();}